# How to uninstall ubuntu grub after formatting ubuntu partition in windows 8?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows

So I tried uninstalling ubuntu from my dual-boot of Windows 8 and Ubuntu (GRUB booted everything)

I formatted the partition for Ubuntu from Windows
I tried booting into windows afterwards and couldn't

I'm simply faced with a GRUB commandline

I tried going into recovery then to command prompt
I tried
`bootrec /FixMbr`
`bootrec /FixBoot`

and none of them worked. I am still booted into the grub command line, is there anyway to fix this and boot back into windows?

Comment: Those commands are to be run after booting Windows (Installation or Repair) CDs and selecting *Repair*, not on Grub.

Answer (score 0):

Try running

> bootrec.exe /RebuildBcd

with a Windows recovery disk.

Answer (score 0):

If `bootrec /fixmbr` didn't work, then chances are you've got an EFI-mode installation. If so, the following command, typed from a Windows Administrator Command Prompt window, should do the trick:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
```

Some EFIs also let you reset the default boot program from their own user interfaces, but details vary greatly from one EFI to another.